# Given a single sample X from $N(0, \theta)$ is $|X|$ a sufficient statistic for $\theta$?

Tags: self-study, inference, nonparametric, sufficient-statistics

My first idea on how to proceed was to treat $|X|$ as piecewise where $X=$ $X$ for $X \in [0, \infty)$ and $-X$ for $X \in (-\infty, 0)$, then use the conditional probability definition for a sufficient statistic (ie, statistic $S(X)=|X|$ sufficient iff $P(X | S(X)=|X|)$ independent of $\theta$). But I cannot figure out how to proceed from here.

(This is an exercise item from Mood, Graybill, and Boes's book)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Do you know the Neyman factorization theorem? That plus $x^2 = |x|^2$ should be "sufficient"

Comment: @Chaconne oh I see. and then $\sqrt{|X|^2}$ will just be a (one-to-one) function of $x^2$ since $x^2$ is a minimal sufficient statistic using Fisher-Neyman factorization? Or is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It seems like you're doing way more work than you need (unless I'm misunderstanding you). If you're just trying to prove sufficiency then all you need to do is show that you can write $f_\theta(x) = g_\theta(T(x))h(x)$. Your statistic certainly does not need to be one-to-one, and in fact probably shouldn't be. The point is that it is a reduction of your data, but if it is one-to-one you haven't reduced it at all.

Comment: I forgot that $x^2$ is equal to $|X|^2$ so using the factorization theorem did not occur to me. I kept forcing using the conditional probability definition for sufficiency.

Comment: @Chaconne I meant the result that a one-to-one function of a sufficient statistic is also sufficient. But it does appear I can get $|X|$ directly using factorization and not have to go through that extra step. In any case, thank you for the help!

Comment: Ah, I now see what you meant with the one-to-oneness. Glad I could be of help.